# sudo apt-get update not working in elementary os freya

Tags: apt

When I try to write `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/.http could not be found.
```

Any ideas how to get this work correctly? What's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a stray dot in there:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/.http
                                          ↑
```

Sounds like a typo. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to see if you have any URLs in there of the form `.http://something/.....`.